# Angular Unit Test (w/ Jest) a service that imports and uses an esm module;

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs

## Explination

I have a unit testing question using Angular (v 9), Jest (24.9.0), and an ECMAScript Module (dialog-polyfill (v 0.5.1) ). This polyfill adds support for the `HTMLDialogElement`. The issue is, it has a method `registerDialog` that needs to be called when the dialog is in the DOM. It takes the dialog element as it's only parameter. This service that I've created, registers the dialog and adds it to an array. Everything works perfectly with the implementation, but the tests fail because it doesn't know what the polyfill is. I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerDialog' of undefined

- Note: I am quite new to testing in Angular and my implementation might not be correct; if so, please let me know.
- Second Note: I'm note sure if there is a better way to create a Dialog Element besides calling `createElement` on the document within the Jest test.

### Dialog Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import dialogPolyfill from 'dialog-polyfill';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DialogService {
  public dialogs$: BehaviorSubject<HTMLDialogElement[]> = new BehaviorSubject<
    HTMLDialogElement[]
  >([]);

  private dialogs: [] = [];

  constructor() {}

  register(dialog: HTMLDialogElement) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    this.dialogs$.next([...this.dialogs, dialog]);
  }
}
```

### Dialog Service Spec

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DialogService } from './dialog.service';

describe('DialogService', () => {
  let service: DialogService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(DialogService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should register a dialog', () => {
    expect(service.dialogs$.getValue().length).toBe(0);
    service.register(document.createElement('dialog'));
    expect(service.dialogs$.getValue().length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

#### References

- [Dialog Polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill/tree/8b458a4b7629eef5d1919dbb4393ee758d202d92)
- [Angular](https://angular.io)
- [Jest JS](https://jestjs.io)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide your service in your TestBed:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [DialogService] 
  });
  service = TestBed.inject(DialogService);
});
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem. The only way that I have found to get around this error is to check if the `dialogPolyfill` actually exists in the service itself:

if (dialogPolyfill) {
  dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
}

Comment: Have you imported that polyfills in main.spec.ts?

Comment: I do not have a `main.spec.ts`. I have a `test-setup.ts` that's importing `jest-preset-angular`.

Comment: Could you check if there's a "test.options.polyfills" attribute in angular.json file?

Comment: Forget it... I've just read here that just doesn't use any of karma configs.

Comment: There wasn't. I updated that property to: `dialogPolyfill` and that didn't work.

Comment: There's something in the docs showing polyfills being mentioned in the files array in tsconfig.spec.ts.

Comment: > The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

Comment: Well, one acceptable alternative is to stop testing if the polyfill is doing its job and trust that somebody did it for you.

Comment: I am not testing if the polyfill is doing it's job. This service not only registers the dialog with the polyfill, but it adds the actual dialog to an array. I'm testing that the service does that. This is just a side affect. 

The other issues I'm having is that since Jest doesn't know about the `HTMLDialogElement`, when I call it's `show` or `showModal` methods, just throws and error because `TypeError: this.dialog.nativeElement.showModal is not a function`. I need a way to polyfill Jest. Or just not test anything with dialogs.

Comment: Are you importing `dialog-polyfill` inside your `polyfills.ts`? If not, try a simple `import 'dialog-polyfill.js` there.

Comment: Yes, It's there.